# cordova plugin add multi-image-picker using

Tags: html, css, angularjs, cordova

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    window.imagePicker.getPictures(
        function(results) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
            {
                alert('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
            }
        }, function (error) {
            alert('Error: ' + error);
        });
    }
```

Image picker plugin using select multiple images from gallery. using this plugin i selected multiple image but how to show in inside html view part.
successCB Callback function when image is selected.

failCB Callback function when no image is selected.

options See Options

Answer (score 0):

results data add into scope variable and then represent in html.(in your view)

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
window.imagePicker.getPictures(
    function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
        {
           $scope.imagelist.push(results[i]);
            alert('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
        }
    }, function (error) {
        alert('Error: ' + error);
    });
}
```

in html

```
 <div ng-repeat="img in imagelist"><img ng-src="img"><div>
```